# Show $|ab| \leq |a||b|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$ and suppose $ab = ba$. The goal is to show that the order of $ab$ is less than or equal to the order of $a$ times the order of $b$.

I started with this:

$|\langle a \rangle | = \#\{a^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\} = n$

$|\langle b \rangle | = \#\{b^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\} = m$

$|\langle ab \rangle | = \#\{(ab)^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \#\{(a^kb^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = k$

Now, we want to show $k \leq mn$, but I don't know any general techniques to show that some number is less than another number. I tried to use information I know about these sets, such as the fact that $a^n = 1$, $b^m = 1$, and $(ab)^k = 1$, but I'm not sure where any of this information is applicable.

Comment: Hint: You can clearly assume that the orders are finite, so the order is the smallest exponent which is the identity element. Now just compute the product of the elements to the product of their orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m,n \in \mathbb N$ be the least numbers so that $a^n=1$ and $b^m=1$.

Then $(ab)^{nm}=(ab)(ab)\cdots(ab)= a^{mn}b^{mn}=(a^{n})^m\cdot (b^{m})^n=1$. Hence, the order of $(ab)$ must be less than or equal to $nm$, since the order, $k$ will be the **least** positive integer so that $(ab)^k=1$.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm a little confused about how you got from $(ab)^{nm} = a^nb^m$. I know that $(ab)^{nm} = a^{nm}b^{nm}$, but I'm just not seeing the connection to $a^nb^m$.

Comment: A silly mistake!

Comment: Note that the first equality is using the hypothesis that $ab=ba$ in a critical way. I edited it to clarify this point

Comment: Oh this makes sense, thank you! And right: commutativity allows us to write $ab$ $nm$ times as $a^{nm}b^{nm}$.

Comment: that's exactly right =).

Comment: That assumption is in the OP

Comment: $ab=ba $ for the two elements. Of course the proof extends to arbitrary elements in yhe case of abelian groups